# Taylor series and falling factorials

Tags: series-expansion

I'm new in *Mathematica* and I have following problem to solve:
 If $f$ is any function $f: R \to R$ which can be represented as a Taylor series in some close neighbourhood $S$ of $0$ , is it true that

[image]
for $x \in S$?

It should be done in *Mathematica* and I completely don't know how to touch the topic. I suppose I should rather find counterexample. Is it any existing build-in function representing difference operator? I just know I should use `FactorialPower` and `Series` for Taylor series. Any tips? Thanks for help!

Comment: What do you mean by "difference operator"?

Answer (score 4):

### Partial answer

For positive integer $x$, the summand is $0$ for $n > x$.

```
f[x_] = Sin[x];
Δ0 = DifferenceDelta[f[x], {x, n}] /. x -> 0;

With[{x = 4},
  Sum[Δ0/n! FactorialPower[x, n], {n, 0, x}] // FullSimplify
]
```

> ```
> Sin[4]
> ```

In general, Mathematica seems to have a hard time summing `DifferenceDelta`, but an easier time if we expand out its definition.

```
summand = FunctionExpand[(-1)^(n + k) Binomial[n, k] f[k]/n! FactorialPower[x, n]];
Sum[summand, {n, 0, ∞}, {k, 0, n}]
```

> ```
> 1/2 I ((E^-I)^x - (E^I)^x)
> ```

```
FullSimplify[%]
```

> ```
> Sin[x]
> ```

Unfortunately this sum can still come back unevaluated for many choices of $f$, let alone a symbolic one. It even chokes on simple functions like $f(x) = x$.